# Error DateTime::__construct(): Failed to Parse time string (nom) at position 0 (n)

Tags: php, symfony

First, excuse me for my english, I'm trying to do an effort to avoid some mistakes.

I have a little problem, because i'm trying to develop my layout, and when I want to run my web pages, I have this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (nom) at position 0 (n)

This is my code:

```
<?php
//src/OC/PlatformBundle/Controller/AdvertController.php

namespace OC\PlatformBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class AdvertController extends Controller{

    Public function indexAction(){
        //On ne sait pas combien de pages il y a 
        //Mais on sait qu'une page doit être supérieur ou égal à 1
        //if ($page < 1){
            //On déclenche une exception NotFoundHttpException, cela va afficher
            //une page d'erreur 404 
            //throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page "'.$page.'" inexistante.');
        //}

        //Ici on récupérera la liste des annonces, puis on la passera au template
        //
        //Mais pour l'instant on ne fait qu'appeler le template

        return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:index.html.twig', array(
                    'listAdverts' => array()
                ));
    }

    Public function viewAction($id){
        //Ici, on récupère l'annonce correspondant à l'id $id
        return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:view.html.twig', array('id' => $id));

    }
```

My layout:

```
{# src/OC/PlatformBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig #}

{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}
  Annonces - {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  {# On définit un sous titre commun à toutes les pages du bundle, par exemple #}

  <h1> Annonces </h1>

  <hr>

  {# On définit un nouveau bloc, que les vues du bundle pourront remplir #}
  {% block ocplatform_body %}
  {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Index:

```
{# src/OC/PlatformBundler/Resources/views/Advert/index.html.twig #}

{% extends "OCPlatformBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}
  Accueil - {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block ocplatform_body %}

  <h2> Liste des annonces </h2>

  <ul>
    {% for advert in listAdverts %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ path('oc_platform_view', {'id': advert.id}) }}">
          {{ advert.title }}
        </a>
        par {{ advert.author }},
        le {{ advert.date|date('d/m/Y') }}
      </li>
    {% else %}
      <li> Pas (encore!) d'annonces </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for help me.

Have a nice day

Comment: yea seems that advert.date have wrong value maybe `null`?

Comment: is the {{ advert.date|date('d/m/Y') }} false ? (In my index???)